# External Dll with umod

Tags: c#, dll

I want to use EntityFramework in my server for a database. When I transfer dll files from bin/debug that I
installed via visual studio nuget, the plugin does not compile with the error: Unhandled exception.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.EnetityFramework.Core.
Everything works great in visual studio. Also, when I create a new project in visual studio with a link to the
Managed folder, where I have already moved these dlls, I also get this error. I don’t understand, I’ve been
struggling with this for 3 days now and nothing helps.

I tried to reload all my server, but it still not working.